# What does the FCM restriction about "100 multiple senders" actually mean?

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

The [FCM documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#receiving-messages-from-multiple-senders) about "multiple senders" declares:

> Note that there is limit of 100 multiple senders.

However, I don't understand what will happen, if I'll try to send FCM message from, for example, 150 senders at the same time (i.e. all of them will use the same FCM token value for the message content).

Currently I have 3 suggestions for this case:

1. 100 most "first" sendings will be successful, and remaining 50 sendings just will be postponed (and executed after finish of previous 100 sendings).
2. 100 sendings will be successful, however remaining 50 sendings will be **not** executed in general.
3. All 150 sendings  will be not executed.

What suggestion is correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *note* is under the ***Receiving messages from multiple senders*** section. This pertains to actual senders, *not messages*. As pointed out in the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#receiving-messages-from-multiple-senders), a specific app can receive messages from multiple sources.

None of the three suggestions apply to the statement, but here's an example:

Say you have a news app where you get to choose from multiple sources. All of the selected sources can send updates(push notifications) towards your app. However, you have a limit of 100 sources. You can't go beyond that. You have to free up space first by removing a source.

For messages however, the most likely error that'd you would receive when a specific device is receiving too much at a given rate is [Device Message Rate Exceeded](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#error-codes):

> The rate of messages to a particular device is too high. If an iOS app sends messages at a rate exceeding APNs limits, it may receive this error message
>
> Reduce the number of messages sent to this device and use exponential backoff to retry sending.

Comment: AL, thanks for your answer. However, I still don't understand one point:

_"All of the selected sources can send updates(push notifications) towards your app. However, you have a limit of 100 sources."_

Does this limit related to each device only, or to **whole** application? If second, can I use more than 100 senders (with same _server key_ but different _sener IDs_) for application generally?

Comment: It's for the app alone. The device has its own restrictions. The limit is 100, you can't use more than that. Using the same server key would only count as a single sender ID -- you can't duplicate a server key for multiple sender IDs (each sender ID is a project on its own so its not possible). The 100 sender limit is actually pretty high as it is. I've never even encountered an app that needed more than 3 senders.

Comment: Thanks for the info. In our application, we assumed usage of about 2000 unique senders for push-notifications. Now, for FCM it's not possible at general, I consider?

Comment: I can't say for sure (without context) if the requirements of a sender for your app is the same as what is suggested as a sender for FCM. But it's good to know that each project can create multiple server keys (via the console) which (iirc) can be used for FCM. In most architectures that I encountered, FCM is a good fit.

Comment: In our app, each "sender" is Windows PC which knows FCM server key (same for all "senders") and FCM token of corresponding phone (different for all "senders"). Number of "senders" is greater than 100 (i.e. about 2000), sendings of push-notifications are separated in time (i.e. only 1-5 "senders" make sendings at the same time). Does this case fit to requirements for _"a sender for FCM"_?

Comment: "*In our app, each "sender" is Windows PC which knows FCM server key (same for all "senders")*" - this counts as 1 sender since they all have the same server key. It's an FCM sender. The thing I'm wondering about is why do you need 2000 machines to send push notifications? (imho) The goal of multiple senders is to be able to provide permission and restrictions as to when and which devices each sender could send a message to.

Comment: _"The thing I'm wondering about is why do you need 2000 machines to send push notifications?"_ - each of these machines is Windows-desktop installation of our main application, which can send push-notifications to several linked phones (which have corresponding mobile application). I.e. each end-user can send notifications by itself, without intermediate server. All of them will use same _server key_, but they never know its value (it's stored in desktop app in ciphered state, and used only inside HTTPS-queries for sending of notifications).